# Holtek Semiconductor's HT67F50 segment display driver interrupt definition

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to write an interrupt routine with HT-IDE3000 but when I write some code inside the routine the linker is giving an error about RAM bank0 overflow. I'm using Holtek C Compiler V3 and user guide says the interrupt vector definition must do as `void __attribute((interrupt(0x24))) TIM0_ISR(){}` instead of old version `#pragma vector TIM_ISR @0x24` then it says "The variables that can be accessed by both the interrupt service routine and other functions are defined as volatile" at page 34 of the Holtek C Compiler V3 User's Guide, my code is;

```
#include "HT67F50.h"

typedef struct
{
    /*volatile*/ uint8_t time2msflag:1;
    /*volatile*/ uint8_t t500msflag:1;
    /*volatile*/ uint8_t t1sflag:1;
    /*volatile*/ uint8_t poweronflag:1;
    const /*volatile*/ uint8_t reserved:4;
}Flag_t;
volatile uint8_t time2ms;
volatile uint8_t t500ms;
volatile uint8_t t1s;
volatile uint16_t time1s_dis;
volatile Flag_t flag;
void __attribute((interrupt(0x24))) TIM_ISR(void)
{
    //_t0af = 0;
    //if (++time2ms >= 2)
    //{
        //time2ms = 0;
        //flag.time2msflag = 1;
        //if (flag.poweronflag)
        //{
            //if (++time1s_dis >= 1000) // power on and all pixels illuminated for 2s
            //{
                //time1s_dis = 0;
                //flag.poweronflag = 0;
            //}
        //}
        //else
        //{
            //if (++t500ms >= 250)
            //{
                //t500ms = 0;
                //flag.t500msflag = ~(flag.t500msflag); // second flash
                //if (++t1s >= 2)
                //{
                    //t1s = 0;
                    //flag.t1sflag = 1;
                //}
            //}
        //}
    //}
}
```

When I uncomment the lines linker's output is;

```
Holtek (R) Cross C Compiler Version V3.4
 Compiling D:\x-yedek\calismalar\holtek\termo\termo\driver\lcd_config.c ...
Holtek (R) Cross-Assembler  Version HGASM0202
Copyright (C) 2002 Holtek Semiconductor INC.  All rights reserved.
D:\x-yedek\calismalar\holtek\termo\termo\lcd_config.ASM
    0 Errors, 0 Warnings
Linking...
Error(L1038) : RAM bank0 overflow, memory allocation fails for section '_rfmSendAck' (size 09H) in the file 'D:\x-yedek\calismalar\holtek\termo\termo\RFM69HC.OBJ'
Unallocated DATA Section List:
Class   Length          Name
DATA       0 [0h]       _adcMainConfig
DATA       0 [0h]       _adcChipInit
DATA       0 [0h]       _adcCalibration
DATA       0 [0h]       _adcRead
DATA       9 [9h]       _portInputInit
DATA       4 [4h]       _setPins
DATA       4 [4h]       _resetPins
DATA       2 [2h]       _getPins
DATA       5 [5h]       _togglePin
DATA       1 [1h]       _setPortAWakeUp
DATA       1 [1h]       _setPotyAWakeUpMulti
DATA       1 [1h]       _resetPortAWakeUp
DATA       1 [1h]       _resetPotyAWakeUpMulti
DATA       3 [3h]       _spiInit
DATA       7 [7h]       _spiReadMulti
DATA       5 [5h]       _rfmInit
DATA       1 [1h]       _rfmSetAddress
DATA       1 [1h]       _rfmNetworkAddress
DATA       7 [7h]       _rfmSendData
DATA       9 [9h]       _rfmSendAck
DATA       0 [0h]       _rfmSetHighestPower
DATA       5 [5h]       _encryption
DATA       0 [0h]       _builtin_holtek_dtnorm
DATA       0 [0h]       _builtin_holtek_dtinf
Total 1 error(s), Total 0 Warning(s)
'termo' - Total 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with creating common used variables at ram bank0 between 0x80h and 0xFFh with adding one ram bank0 address definition and changing variable creation lines;

```
#define RAM_BANK0 0x80

static volatile uint8_t time2ms __attribute__((at(RAM_BANK0)));
static volatile uint8_t t500ms  __attribute__((at(RAM_BANK0 + 1)));
static volatile uint8_t t1s  __attribute__((at(RAM_BANK0 + 2)));
static volatile uint16_t time1s_dis __attribute__((at(RAM_BANK0 + 3)));
static volatile Flag_t flag __attribute__((at(RAM_BANK0 + 5)));
```